# pytorch-tabnet installation error: No matching distribution found

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Trying to install pytorch-tabnet on my windows 10 with the latest anaconda distribution. Python version is 3.9.7 and pip version 21.2.4

I first updated conda

```
> conda clean -all
> conda update -all

I cloned base environment into new environment called tabnet

> conda create --name tabnet --clone base
> conda activate tabnet

and tried to install pytorch-tabnet using

(tabnet)> pip install pytorch-tabnet
```

after several warning messages, I get the following error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch-tabnet (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch-tabnet.

I guess the python version I have may not be compatible.  Any suggestions on what would be a compatible environment for pytorch-tabnet?  Even better if someone is happy to share their environment.yml file where they have a working version of pytorch-tabnet is set.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pytorch-tabnet installation worked with python 3.6.

So I installed pytorch implementation of tabnet in a fresh environment with python 3.6.  the only other library I installed in that environment is jupyterlab.

Also note there also exists a tensor flow installation of tabnet